# I can write to a usb stick but i can't change permissions

Tags: unity, usb, permissions

I have seen many problems relating to not being able to write to a usb stick, but those do not apply as i can write, but cannot change permissions of files on the usb stick. I am trying to install unity on a usb stick, and i did `sudo mv` to move the files to the stick. when i do sudo chmod or use the permissions window to change the permissions of the unity run file, they immediately revert to read only. Is it possible to change the permissions of the usb stick without formatting? It has occurred to me that, in the properties menu, it says that the filesystem type is msdos. This might be the problem, but if there are any ways to change the permissions of an unformatted usb stick, they would be useful no matter what. Thanks in advance!

Comment: >remount it with the permissions. how do i change the permissions if it is not mounted? I might be misunderstanding what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS-DOS filesystem *does not have permissions*.
Advanced permissions simply are not part of the filesystem. You can only mark them `A`,`S`,`H`,`I`. On the old MS-DOS, you use the [ATTRIB command](https://www.computerhope.com/attribhl.htm):

```
ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+I | -I] [drive:][path][file name] [/S [/D] [/L]]
```

The following are the attributes of an MS-DOS filesystem:

- `R`   Read-only file attribute.
- `A`   Archive file attribute.
- `S`   System file attribute.
- `H`   Hidden file attribute.

There are no group or owner permissions to manipulate if your USB stick is formatted with an MS-DOS/vFAT filesystem. So your only option would be to reformat this USB stick with another filesystem.

Comment: Thanks! I guess ill have to reformat.